# How to prevent directory browsing of S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a ton of files on my S3 bucket and add a bucket policy to make them all public.
Now it lists the entire directory (or the first 1000 items) when I browse the root.
How can I prevent directory browsing?

Comment: Hiya, please consider changing the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 117):

It should be noted that adding an index.html file to a bucket does absolutely nothing. This file will simply be listed with all other files when browsing the bucket root.

Also, setting access levels on the bucket so that 'everyone' cannot read, means that every new file you upload to your bucket will need to have its permission set to 'everyone' before it can be browsed. This isn't practical if you're adding files regularly.

The best solution is to first set access levels on the bucket to deny 'everyone' read access, but then create a bucket policy that allows everyone to read what's inside the bucket. This way, nobody will be able to list the contents of your bucket, but any new files you add will be readable by everyone who has the link to that file.

Here is what the bucket policy might look like. Replace 'my_bucket' with your bucket name, and you're good to go.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: **This is the correct answer.** Specifically note the implementation of a bucket policy *instead* of the "Everyone/Read" broad access.

Comment: I couldnt get this to work in 2017 (not sure if something has updated) but there is an option under the S3 management console that says "list objects" you can just remove that but still allow read access to achieve the same thing

Comment: @Usman That's not correct. You still need a bucket policy in 2017 to allow read access to individual files in your bucket, without allowing all items in bucket to be listed from the bucket root. The bucket policy above still works in 2017, I use it and it works as described. Without a bucket policy, individual files in your bucket will not be readable unless you manually grant permission for each individual file. The objective is to deny listing at the root, while allowing access to files in the bucket, much like a normal web server. You can't achieve this without a bucket policy.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't wan't people to see the listing of the objects inside my bucket, but I did want them to be able to read individual objects. Using the policy above and turning off "List Objects" for "Everyone" in the "Public Access" section of "Permissions" of my bucket.

Comment: do we have any option to allow bucket access from IP and domain name. I want to use both IP and domain name in bucket policy so that bucket will be accessible from both ip and domain name

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way is probably to edit the settings:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [ACL](http://zsvoboda.blogspot.com/2009/01/amazon-s3-acl-script.html) on the directory and the individual files independently, do not give read permissions on the directory but allow it for the individual files. There are many tools to help with this including [bucket explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--access-control-list-details.html) or s3 fox.

Comment: thanks. Just realized that my dragondisk tool can do this as well.

Comment: bucketexplorer link is dead

Answer (score 2):

A bucket policy should no longer be needed for this, as far as I'm aware (it probably was back when the answers to this question were first posted).

Now, just set your bucket to public access but turn off the "List Objects" permission.

Comment: No.  If you want to make all file in a bucket public (and any future files you upload automatically public) and still prevent directory browsing, you need a bucket policy. With your method, individual files are not public. I'm in the console right now confirming this on my bucket. A policy is still needed. Maybe try it yourself!

Comment: @hiJump can you elaborate or point me to how should a policy for that look like? I have tried removing the ListObjects from my policy but it did not work as expected. I am using terraform to manage the bucket's policies.

Answer (score 2):

There are **four type of s3 security and policies** you could apply as of **May 2020**

- IAM policies
- Bucket Policies
- Object Access Control List (ACL)
- Bucket Access Control List (ACL)

Among them you can User Bucket Policies to apply policies

**Line to Focus Just put `/*` after bucket_name in Resource as below**

```
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy212127",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt112121212",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Bucket policy]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In the ACL's everyone had List permission. I changed that to Read.
[ACL with List Permission][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEzj0.png

[ACL with read permission][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErRO.png